# How to check for a specific View Controller in Xcode using an IF Statement?

Tags: ios, swift

I have written the following code to detect if touches in my Game View Controller. But, when I perform a segue to another view Controller and since the Game view controller is not dismissed, it detects touch and crashes the app. Is there any way by which I can check for touches only in the Game View Controller using an IF statement to my code given below? Would appreciate your help! Thanks:)

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  // First touch to start the game
  if gameState == .ready {
    startGame()
  }
  
  if let touchLocation = event?.allTouches?.first?.location(in: self.view) {
    // Move the player to the new position
    movePlayer(to: touchLocation)
    
    // Move all enemies to the new position to trace the player
    moveEnemies(to: touchLocation)
  }

}
```

Comment: where this code snippet inside ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan Inside the Game View Controller Class

Comment: Try to compare `self.view == touches.first?.view`

Comment: @iUrii shall I include this code inside touchesBegan function?

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare a touch's view with the view of your controller e.g.:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    
    guard view == touches.first?.view else {
        return
    }
    ...
}
```